# C# - Xamarin Forms audio player stops working after 5 or 6 uses

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin

I am using this implementation of an Audio Player in Xamarin

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088094/Playing-audio-mp-File-in-Xamarin-Forms

I have a button in my code that, when pressed, plays a certain, short (1-2 seconds) tone.

The player in the link works well, but for some reason if I repeatedly press my button like 5 or 6 times the audio player doesnt work anymore. Even if I leave the page and come back the audio player still doesn't work. What could be causing this? I'm fearing that it might be a device security thing on Android, because why else would it play the first few times?

Here is my code for clicking the button

```
    void PlayChordClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile(myMp3);
    }
```

Everything else is exactly as copied from the tutorial.
Thanks!

Comment: That code (the one on the article) doesn't dispose the players after finishing, that can lead to a ton of problems, add code to destroy the old players when they finish.

Comment: *Gulp* I don't know how :(

Comment: Then learn how to do it :)

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction? Is it as easy as adding a single line "player.Dispose();" at the end of the method?

Comment: Dude, why don't you read the Xamarin documentation about MediaPlayer and AVPlayer? Hook to the correct events and Dispose the objects.

Comment: Cool. Well I believe that was the problem :D! I added a delegate in the AudioService class where upon completion it would dispose the player. It is still a little laggy after many clicks, but it doesn't permanently stop playing anymore. If you would like me to give you best answer for helping me out, then leave an answer saying "Helped in comments" or something and I will give you best answer for your help.

Comment: No problem, I'm really glad you finally took the time to learn. Remember, documentation is always your friend, read it first, and if you still have doubts, then ask for help.

Comment: Add the answer by yourself as you are the one who has the full answer, you will gain points also ;)

Comment: Hey Gusman, sorry for bothering you but something unexpected came up and Im unsure the reason. I edited my code and added the "player.Release()" line and that combined with the Dispose got rid of the problems I was having. Any reason why this would be? I thought that the dispose would have done the release itself, instead of having to do it explicitly.

Comment: Well, Xamarin isn't perfect, indeed the expected behavior is that, but for some reason they aren't doing it. And the docs says this must be explicitly called when the player isn't needed any more, they even describe your exact problem: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Media.MediaPlayer.Release/

Answer (score 4):

With help from Gusman in the comments, I figured out that I was most likely crashing the app by not disposing of the MediaPlayer after using it.

I added these few lines in the Android "PlayAudioFile" method and it did the trick

```
player.Completion += delegate
{
    player.Release();
    player.Dispose();
};
```